# differences between ng-submit and ng-click

Tags: angularjs, submit, form-submit, angularjs-ng-click

In angularjs I'm wondering what the differences are between ng-submit and ng-click?  Specifically, pros and cons of each and when should you one or the other?  Thanks!

****EDIT****
I've looked in to this a bit more but I'm still wondering what (if any) the benefit is of using ng-submit?  Could you use an ng-click in place of all ng-submits?  Would this cause any problems? Thanks again!

Comment: Both are just wrappers around the native browser events.

Comment: Here's an interesting post that will probably help demystify this issue http://bit.ly/1TUTAAz

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The ngSubmit directive binds to the [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/submit) in the browser, which is fired when a form is submitted.

From MDN:

> Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

So you might use it to submit a user sign-up form, or something like that.

On the other hand, the ngClick directive can apply to any kind of element.

From [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L3):

> The ngClick directive allows you to specify custom behavior when an
>   element is clicked.

Use it to allow your user to interact with your page in some way other than submitting a form.  Maybe to click on a 'previous' or 'next' pager button, or maybe a map or something.

Answer (score 25):

Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the  element has **action**, **data-action**, or **x-action** attributes specified.So when using angular with forms without these atributes **ng-click** and **ng-submit** can be used to specify which javascript method to call.In either call you can get all input values in a scope because of  two-way data binding property of angular. 
***Could you use an ng-click in place of all ng-submits? Would this cause any problems?***
it can be used but when using ng-click it does not take html input attributes (like required,min-max,maxlength) into account and executes method body immediately.

Comment: Thank you, this removes the misconception. So for submitting forms, ng-submit is preferred. For any other interactions, ng-click is what to use.

Comment: `when using ng-click it does not take html input attributes (like required,min-max,maxlength) into account and executes method body immediately`............ +1 for demystifying this!

Answer (score 17):

My favorite reason for using `ng-submit` is that it allows you to press the `<Enter>` key while focused on a form input etc. and the form will submit. (Assuming of course that you have a button of `type="submit"` in the form.)

Its more keyboard friendly and accessibility friendly than having `ng-click` on a button, because with `ng-submit`, a user can click on the submit button or they can press `<Enter>`.

Comment: I was just testing this, and it appears the function runs by pressing enter both ways. I thought this was a benefit of ngSubmit as well, but from my test just now it appears to act the same either way.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't understand how the function can run without having `ng-submit`. Placing the `ng-submit` attribute on the form is what allows you to define the function to run when the `<Enter>` key is pressed while you are focused on one of the elements of said form. How else would you define a function to run on `<Enter>` if you don't have an `ng-submit`?

Comment: If change the button "Type" to submit, it does the same-thing(<=Horrible chrome auto correct.)...

Answer (score 4):

If we want the form not to be submitted when it is invalid, then instead of ng-click on the button, we will use ng-submit directive on the form itself

```
    <div class="row">
        <form name="adduser" ng-submit="AddUser(adduser.$valid)">                   
            <div id="name-group" class="form-group-lg">
                <input type="text"
                       required
                       name="name"
                       ng-model="userfullName"
                       class="form-control"
                       placeholder="Full Name">
            </div>
```

In the ng-submit we calling a function AddUser from the controller with a parameter formname.$valid. This submit function will be only called when form is valid or in other words all the user input of the form is valid. Keep in mind that in this case from would not be submitted if form is not valid

When we use ng-click , form will be submitted even if it is invalid. Two observations for ng-click are as follows:

We were able to submit the form even if form was not valid
For the invalid inputs, the value was set to undefined in the controller

Answer (score 3):

ng-submit associated with forms, this event fires when u submit form. Where as ng-click can work without form submit event