# Angularjs use ng-submit or ng-click for login

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs and web development. Currently I'm working on a small project which requires login. I have the server side code finished and tested.

My current approach is to use ng-click on "Log in" button and invoke the async method to send the post request to the server.

However, I also saw other people are using ng-submit for the "Log in".
At this point, I don't know which approach is the best solution or is the most angular way of doing the login.

I also need to display the on-screen validation to user when their password and username don't match.

Please give me some advice below and I will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are using a form tag, use ng-submit, but you can archive the same result using ng-click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ngSubmit directive binds to the [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/submit) in the browser, which is fired when a form is submitted.

From MDN:

> Note that submit is fired only on the form element, not the button or submit input. (Forms are submitted, not buttons.)

So you might use it to submit a user sign-up form, or something like that.

On the other hand, the ngClick directive can apply to any kind of element.

From [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L3):

> The ngClick directive allows you to specify custom behavior when an
>   element is clicked.

Use it to allow your user to interact with your page in some way other than submitting a form.  Maybe to click on a 'previous' or 'next' pager button, or maybe a map or something.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23553071/differences-between-ng-submit-and-ng-click/23553462#23553462)

Comment: Yeah I read this thread before but it didn't quite answer my quest just yet. I understand that both ways can achieve the same result. However what I don't know is that which approach offers more space for me to add some UI effects (say mark the input text box red and show validation messages below the text box). Also when I tried to use "ng-submit" I saw the process bar on the bowser is loading something, then after the loading the browser refresh the page (maybe?). I tried many different webpages and I saw both approaches... So I'm so confused right now. Or I shouldn't be worried at all?

Comment: Yeah I've decided to use ng-submit. Thanks for all the helps.